# How to say “that”? “Que” or “qui”?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées

I'm beginning to study French and I have a very basic doubt: how to say “that” in French. I don't mean “cette”, “ce” or “ça”. For example:

- I think that all the girls in Montreal are pretty
- Je pense **que** toutes les femmes de Montréal sont très belles.

I understand that it is “que”, but reading sometimes I see “qui”. Is there some rule to apply it?

Comment: Can you show an example of "Qui".

Comment: @milk2go I think this is not a good example, but is the one I remembered where to find =]: Qu'est-ce qui change dans une phrase interrogative quand on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good [link](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/relativepronouns_2.htm) that will help you. It explains the difference between the 2 relative pronouns.